# Link phone number to a Firebase user Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

I have a registration screen where the user enters **Email, Password and Phone Number.**

Then, I create a user with the email and password:

```
Future<String> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return 'Registered successfully';
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

After this I have a **VerifyOTP** screen where I have to verify the phone number entered using OTP.  **Once the phone number is verified, I want to link it with the account created.**

How should I link it with the account created? Please help me

I just want the users phone number to be verified but, ***I don't want login via PhoneNumber***

Comment: Maybe try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841486/how-do-i-update-a-firebaseusers-phone-number-in-firebase-auth