# How to update phone number in Firebase when sim card is changed?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter project I can sign in with phone authentication and subsequently creating profile in firebase linked with this user uid. But don't know how to handle the process when user changes the sim card and needs access to his datas. How are you handling this process?

Edit: User lost his number and bought a new one. How can he change his previous number to the new one as in login, phone number gets code from firebase which authenticates the user. If I should insert previous number to update it (i have lost it or changed it), then how firebase will authenticate or update old number without code from firebase.

Comment: Sign in is associated with the phone number, and not with the SIM card. If the user changes their phone number, you'll need to update it by calling `updatePhoneNumberCredential`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841486/how-do-i-update-a-firebaseusers-phone-number-in-firebase-auth

Comment: Thanks Frank for the answer. Lets assume I lost my phone and bought new phone and new number and I want to get datas associated with my previous number. How am I going to achieve that? In login page how I am going to check if previous number is releated to this user to let him update his number when he has no access to his datas?

Comment: There's nothing built into Firebase Authentication for that type of transfer, as (without being able to send a message to the old phone) there is no way to verify account ownership on that API level. You'll typically want to allow the user to create a new Firebase account, and then allow them to transfer their data to the new UID after **you** have verified they're the same user.

Comment: Thanks for response. To transfer user's old datas to the new UID is collapse of the app's internal structure. User old UID is saved in different collection and documents and in this case I have to change all of them which will cause problems in some functionalities.

Comment: I get that this is annoying. You can update the phone number through the Admin SDK too if you want: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank for your time and effort.