# Save additional data to firebase auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've created a signup screen on my Flutter app that uses createUserWithEmailAndPassword() to create and authenticate users using Firebase Authentication. Along with email and password, the signup screen also includes a field for the user's name. I want to save the name as well as the email and password to the user's account in Firebase Authentication. How can I accomplish this?

```
try {
                        FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: _emailTextController.text.trim(),
                                password: _passwordTextController.text.trim()
                                )
                            .then((value) {
                          print("Created New Account");
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => SignInScreen()));
                        }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                          print("Error ${error.toString()}");
                        });
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                        Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
                      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods that firebase_auth provide that allow you to set additional details, you could for example use the updateDisplayName to save their name

[image: firebase_auth methods for updating user data]

If you need to store more complex information about the user, you will need to save the user's ID to a database and read/write information from there

So something like

```
try {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _emailTextController.text.trim(),
        password: _passwordTextController.text.trim()
    ).then((value) {
       value.user?.updateDisplayName("SET USERNAME"); // Update their display name

       print("Created New Account");
       Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(                                builder: (context) => SignInScreen()));
       }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
            print("Error ${error.toString()}");
       });
   } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
       print(e);
       Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
   }
```

Comment: this works for the names, but when trying to give phone number to user by the updatePhoneNumber comand, it says _'The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PhoneAuthCredential'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
TextEditingController _phoneController'_

Comment: Ah yea it looks like phone numbers are a bit different, first you have to verify the phone number, then it can be added to the user's profile. This seems to be the way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841486/how-do-i-update-a-firebaseusers-phone-number-in-firebase-auth